# how to get frequencies versus time without using spectrogram?

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft, frequency-analysis, spectrogram

How can I get frequency versus time of signal which varies in time?

I post my code below, to calculate fft of sinewave, there is any solution without using spectrogram?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
f = 15 #fréquence
f1 = 2
f_s = 2000 # Fréq d'éch
t = np.linspace(0, 10, 10 * f_s, endpoint=False) # axe des temps
fct = np.exp(1/(t+1))
y = np.sin(f1 * 2 * np.pi * t )
x = np.sin(f * 2 * np.pi * t + y) # sinusoide avec une fréquence variable
fig, figure1 = plt.subplots()
figure1.plot(t, x)
figure1.set_xlim(0, 10)
from scipy import fftpack
X = fftpack.rfft(x)
# création de l'axe des fréquences
freqs = fftpack.rfftfreq(len(x)) * f_s
# Génération d'une figure
fig, figure = plt.subplots()
figure.plot(freqs, np.abs(X))
figure.set_xlim(0, 32)
```

Comment: Where do you bring in your data? It looks like you just copied some code from web page somewhere without understanding it.

Comment: i juste tried to calculate fft!

Comment: Well, you have solved half your problem by calculating the magnitudes at each frequency. Then you need to do that again over time to get how it changes over time.

Comment: if we assume that it is a signal that changes frequency over time, I would like to create a graph that translates the frequency as a function of time but without using the spectrogram. because I need this function to apply another fft

Comment: You have functions that calculate the fft of your signal. Check here: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.fft.html